# How to set environment variable for my docker image using azure pipeline variable?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have a azure pipeline that I want to use to deploy my rails app.
The app has a Dockerfile and a docker-compose file.

I am trying to set the RAILS_MASTER_KEY as a secret variable in my pipeline and then reference it as environment variable in my docker compose file.

I can confirm that the agent is setting the variable correctly using echo in the pipeline yaml. However, The environment variable is not getting passed/set properly to my docker-compose and ultimately Dockerfile.

I have troubleshoot this for days reading azure docs, stack overflow and its not working.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

Here is my code:

azure-pipelines.yaml:

```
steps:
  - script: echo "test $(RAILS_MASTER_KEY)"
  - script: echo "test $(testvar)"
  - task: DockerCompose@0
    inputs:
      containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
      azureSubscription: 'de-identified'
      azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":""de-identified"", "id" : "de-identified"}'
      dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
      dockerComposeFileArgs: |
        RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$(RAILS_MASTER_KEY)
        testvar=$(testvar)
      action: 'Build services'
    env:
      RAILS_MASTER_KEY: $(RAILS_MASTER_KEY)
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0' && echo ${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}
      testvar: ${testvar}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.1.0-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    postgresql-client \
    git \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.3.5
ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV RAILS_MASTER_KEY ${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}
ENV testvar ${testvar}
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES true
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
RUN echo "----------------key is 1. ${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}"
RUN echo "----------------key is 11. $( testvar )"
RUN echo "----------------key is 12. $testvar"
RUN echo "----------------key is 2. $[variables.RAILS_MASTER_KEY]"
RUN echo "----------------key is 4. $(RAILS_MASTER_KEY)"
RUN gem install bundler -v $BUNDLER_VERSION
RUN bundle config set --local without 'development test'
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
RUN rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-e", "production", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

As you can see, I have echo trying when trying to debug this so please ignore all echo statements.
Any help/guide will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

From the above snippets, it seems you're using the `dockerComposeFileArgs` to specify environment variables.
One option that comes in handy for similar situations (and for local debugging purposes) is to use `ARG` into `Dockerfile`.
e.g.

```
FROM ruby:3.1.0-slim

RUN ...

ARG RAILS_MASTER_KEY
ENV RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$RAILS_MASTER_KEY

...
```

so you'll have the possibility to specify the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` value at build-time using `secret` variables from Azure DevOps

Here you can find some useful posts talking about `ENV` and `ARGS` keywords:

- https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-time-env-values/
- https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-pass-environment-info-during-docker-builds-1f7c5566dd0e